# How to integrate jms with RESTful web service JAX-RS Jersey using tomcat

Tags: java, rest, jms, tomcat7

I have created a RESTful service using JAX-RS Jersey and deployed it on a tomcat 7 server.

Now I would like to implement JMS. How to implement jms in rest webservices.Please give me any sample example program.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: these are two different concepts that you can implement separately and of course both can communicate with each other. I mean, there is nothing special about them working with each other (Unless there is something I'm not understanding in your question!)

Comment: thank you very much for given suggestion.I have one doubt  Restful web-services is synchronous, how to change asynchronous ,could you please give me suggestion.

Comment: jersey allow asynchronous call.. you can find more information here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html